# Twenty meters of wire is available for fencing off a flower-bed in the form of a circular sector.

Tags: circles, area

**20 meters of wire** is available for fencing off a flower-bed in the form of a **circular sector**.

Then what is the **maximum area** (in sq. m) of the flower-bed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple question. Let $M$ be the angle, the arc of the sector $AOB$ makes with the center $O$. Let OA = OB = radius r.

Given 
$$ OA + arc AB + OB = 20 $$
$$2r + rM = 20 $$
$$ M = {20-2r}{r}$$

Area $A$ of the sector =$ \frac{M}{2}r^2 = 10r-r^2$

$$\frac{dA}{dr}= 10 - 2r = 0$$ 
$$r=5$$

Second derivative is negative for $r =5$

We get maximum area at $r=5$

$A = 25 $

Comment: can you tidy up the maths typesetting? It's quite difficult to follow.

Comment: an edit is suggested @Sanjay Bhatnagar